# Laravel session are not storing

Tags: php, laravel, session

I just deployed my code from my local env to my production env with Forge. But now when I submit my login form I get an error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php.

When I turn of the CSRF protection. And fill in fake data I do get redirected back but the page doesn't give me any errors. Which should like on my local env. When I do Session::set('test', true) and Session::get('test') (on the same page) I do get a true.

I've done some tests, conclusion: my sessions won't work.

I tried many solutions on many forums, nothing worked. Here is my [session config file](http://pastebin.com/jHr5S6JB).

Comment: When you refresh the page does the `<input name="_token">` field keep changing value?

Comment: @GaryGreen No it keeps the same. The token **is not** refreshing.

Comment: @GaryGreen In .env I removed the last slash from ``SESSION_DOMAIN`` from my IP. Now the token does change on every refresh.

Comment: Make sure you've included all your storage folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.env` the I removed the `http://` and the last `/` from the `SESSION_DOMAIN`. This did the trick for me.

So i.e. `127.0.0.1` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/`